# Ruby - checking if file is a CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have just wrote a code where I get a csv file passed in argument and treat it line by line ; so far, everything is okay. Now, I would like to secure my code by making sure that what we receive in argument is a .csv file.

I saw in the Ruby doc that it exist a == "--file" option but using it generate an error : the way I understood it, it seems this option only work for the txt files.

Is there a method specific that allowed to check if my file is a csv ? Here some of my code :

```
    if ARGV.empty?
       puts "j'ai rien reçu"
    # option to check, don't work 
    elsif ARGV[0].shift == "--file"

    # my code so far, whithout checking  
    else  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row|
```

etc, etc...

Comment: Yeah, by a simple command line : `./nameofmyscript nameofmyfile`

Answer (score 3):

I think it is unpossible to make a real safe test without additional information.

Just some notes what you can do:
You get a filename in a variable filename.

First, check if it is a file:

```
File.exist?
```

Then you could check, if the encoding  is correct:

```
raise "Wrong encoding" unless content.valid_encoding?
```

Has your csv always the same number of columns? And do you have only one liner?
This can be a possibility to make the next check:

```
content.each_line{|line|
  return false if line.count(sep) < columns - 1
}
```

This check can be modified for your case, e.g. if you have always an exact number of rows.

In total you can define something like:

```
require 'csv'
#columns defines the expected numer of columns per line
def csv?(filename, sep: ';', columns: 3)
  return false unless File.exist?(filename) #"No file" 
  content = File.read(filename, :encoding => 'utf-8')
  return false unless content.valid_encoding? #"Wrong encoding" 

  content.each_line{|line|
    return false if line.count(sep) < columns - 1
  }
  CSV.parse(content, :col_sep => sep)

end

if csv = csv?('test.csv')
  csv.each do |row|
    p row
  end
end
```

Comment: Checking for the number of columns won't work if some fields are quoted and have new lines, as such rows will be split across several lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ruby-filemagic` gem

```
gem install ruby-filemagic
```

Usage:

```
$ irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'filemagic' 
=> true
irb(main):002:0> fm = FileMagic.new
=> #<FileMagic:0x7fd4afb0>
irb(main):003:0> fm.file('foo.zip') 
=> "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract"
irb(main):004:0>
```

https://github.com/ricardochimal/ruby-filemagic

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, it is a good idea, though I'm afraid that, if I transmit my script to another machine and that the gem is not installed in it, it will not work. Are you sure there is not a method directly in Ruby ?

Comment: If you create a gem for your application you can add following line to your gemspec file: `add_runtime_dependency('ruby-filemagic')` and it will get installed as a dependency.

Comment: thats the deal with gems. thats why RubyGems are so cool . you can jsut easily isntal then by your gemfile. dont be scared homie!

Answer (score -1):

Use ***File.extname()*** to check the origin file

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
```

Comment: ya, but that just checks the extension which is unsecure.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Seems a good solution to me. Thanks, Artyom

Comment: so if i take a mpeg file and change the extension to .csv your test is passing. if you need to be 100% secure, you need to check the content type !

Comment: MIME::Types.type_for(@some_file).first.content_type

Comment: The file's extension is not related to its content. An extension is a string that some apps use as a hint of the content in a file, however it is not a guarantee that the content is that file type. Sniffing the content of the file is a much more valid test, and that can be fooled as even the "magic" tests don't look at every byte in the file.